# Product term as a constant

Tags: products

I am wondering how to treat a constant in a product e.g.:

$\prod_{i=1}^{3} 2$

My best guess would be:

for a constant $ c \in \mathbb{R}$

$\prod_{i=l}^{u} c = c^{u-l+1}$

Answer (score 1):

This is right. You can think of the constant as a trivial function of the dummy index.